# primefaces datatable variable is not initialized correctly

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, panel, commandlink

I've get the following code:

```
<p:dataTable var="message"
                id="messages"
                emptyMessage="No messages"
            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
                {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                value="#{messagesManagedBean.dataModel}" 
            paginator="true" 
            rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30" 
            rows="10"
            lazy="true">
            <p:column width="30%"
                      sortBy="#{message.msgTime}" 
                      filterBy="#{message.text}" 
                      >
                <p:panel id="messageid" 
                     header="#{message.sender.nickname}:#{message.msgTime}"
                     style="color: ;text-align: left; background-color: #{message.sender.userId eq messagesManagedBean.currentUser.userId ? '#B7FFFF' : '#C5FFD4'}">
                     <f:facet name="actions">
                        <p:commandLink
                            styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-corner-all 
                            ui-state-default ui-icon ui-icon-close"
                            action="#{messagesManagedBean.deleteMessage(message.msgId)}"
                            update=":table">
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:graphicImage value="#{message.sender.avatarUrl}" width="100" height="100"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{message.text}" />
                </p:panel>
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

There is a screenshot:
[image]

Obviously, when I'm clicking on the cross, the message should be deleted by {messagesManagedBean.deleteMessage(message.msgId)} method.
The problem is that at the first time, message==null.
When I'm clicking on the cross at the second time, deleteMessage method isn't invoked at all!!
At the third time, everything is all right and I get correct message object.

How can I "initialize" message variable in advance?

Comment: Try setting the `process` attribute of that `<p:commandLink>` to `@this` (`<p:commandLink process="@this"...>`).

Comment: Does that link work only when you click **the same** link thrice?

Comment: what if you change the action of the commandLink to an actionListener? And why do you need to update the table at that time? Does't the panel close? by itself?

Comment: @Tiny 
No, for example, I can click on another message twice.
It begans to work after some action with the form. For example, after typing something on **another** form...

Comment: @Kukeltje
I've changed an action to an actionListener. Now, it works after two clicks. (At the first time the message object is null, at the second - all right).

As far as I understand, the panel shouldn't close without an update attribute.

Comment: The panel in the PF showcase does this (afaics) please create a full but minimal example see [ask]  maybe you have nested forms